# Truecrypt Hidden Volume is Corrupted

Tags: disk-encryption, truecrypt

Hi I have been using Truecrypt for a long time. And I encrypted 20GB drive using that. In which 15GB is outer volume and 5GB is hidden volume. Now what happened is, When I try to open the drive using correct password the drive is getting mounted but when I click on the drive it showing

```
G:\ is not accessible.
The disc structure is corrupted and unreadable
```

But the outer volume(15GB is still accessible). Some one suggest me a working way to recover the hard disc. I need the data inside the drive badly.

Comment: "I need the data inside the drive badly." ..... This ...is... why... you....do... BACKUPS !

Comment: Short of hiring a forensic team, you're probably out of luck

Comment: Did you make any changes in the outer volume lately? If you are using a hidden volume, be aware that you are not supposed to open and save any more data to the outer volume unless you enable Hidden Volume Protection. Neglecting this will likely corrupt the hidden volume as an intended design feature to protect plausible deniability. See the Truecrypt [user guide](https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/TrueCrypt%20User%20Guide.pdf), page 40.

Comment: Once you discovered the error, did you save an exact copy of the disk? E.g. stop using it? If so, are you willing to send it out to disk recovery? If not, are you capable of doing (likely NTFS) recovery your self?

Comment: Did you ever mount the outer volume without entering the hidden volume password for protection? If yes, that's likely responsible for the corruption.